# how to use java in xcode 3.2.1?

Tags: java, xcode

I'm creating a project in Java using XCode 3.2.1.....

But it is giving an error 'Build.xml does not exist'. The file is present in my build folder...... What should I do???

Comment: Use XCode only if you're developing Objective C apps. Don't torture yourself. There are many *far* better IDEs out there for Java. eg. Eclipse.

Comment: I'm going to upvote so you can leave comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest getting the Free version of Intellij IDEA from JetBrains. It is MUCH better at doing Java development than Xcode is by a long shot.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find example projects in `/Developer/Examples/Java/`. `/Developer/Examples/Java/JFC/TableExample` may be apropos.